# How can i reach of selected item's title and item's value in picker in swift?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

Let me describe view controller (page design) side first. I added one picker view, one label and one button, here is my viewController file

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    //var myArray2 = [["Alex", "de Souza", "1977"],["Ariel", "Ortega", "1974"],["Lefter", "KucukAndonyadis", "1925"]]
    //structure of myArray2: name, lastname, bday

    var myArray = ["Alex", "de Souza", "1977"]

    var indexValueOfSelectedItem = 0
    var nameValueOfSelectedItem = ""
    var lastnameValueOfSelectedItem = ""
    var bdateOfSelectedItem = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerStudent: UIPickerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerStudent.delegate = self
        pickerStudent.dataSource = self
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        indexValueOfSelectedItem = row
        //nameValueOfSelectedItem = row
        //lastnameValueOfSelectedItem = row
        //bdateOfSelectedItem = row
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        lblResult.text = String (indexValueOfSelectedItem)
    }
}
```

If i use myArray2 instead of myArray, how can i reach name of selected item details, like name, last name etc ? I would like to show name, lastname and bday of selected item in label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myArray2[row][0]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myArray2.count
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        indexValueOfSelectedItem = row

        print("name: \(myArray2[indexValueOfSelectedItem][0])")
        print("last name: \(myArray2[indexValueOfSelectedItem][1])")
        print("birthdate: \(myArray2[indexValueOfSelectedItem][2])")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. but this shows name, lastname, bday in picker. I would like to show only names. but i would like reach selected item's lastname, bday, name and index with different variables which i have declared in global scope before lblResult outlet defination @Khushbu

Comment: @user3615345 I have edited my answer as per your requirements.

Comment: This is what i want. appriciated. @Khushbu

Answer (score 0):

```
var pickerDataSource = [["Alex", "de Souza", "1977"],["Ariel", "Ortega", "1974"],["Lefter", "KucukAndonyadis", "1925"]]


var selectedModel = ["", "", ""]


@IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerStudent: UIPickerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
pickerStudent.delegate = self
pickerStudent.dataSource = self
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedModel = pickerDataSource[row]
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    print(selectedModel)
}
```

Comment: titleForRow gives an error: cannot convert return expression of '[String]' to return type 'String?' @Taimoor Suleman (thanks)

Comment: cannot convert return expression of '[String]' to return type 'String?' @Taimoor Suleman

Comment: try this line in title for row
return pickerDataSource[row][0]

Comment: Now, it works. I get whole selected row. So i can parse it, right? Because i get name, lastname, bday all together like this: "Lefter", "KucukAndonyadis", "1925"] @Taimoor Suleman

Comment: yes, If you find it as a correct answer, please mark it as correct answer and upvote.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get value by

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
lblResult.text =  myArray[pickerStudent.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]} }
```

and for getting selected index you can user

```
pickerStudent.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
```

using delegate method you can get value when user scrolls the picker view but what if user don't scroll and want to select the first data then you can use this method and you don't need any delegate method also